# Relation that is neither symmetric, asymmetric, not symmetric or antisymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A = {1,2,3,4}

R = {(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (3,1), (3,3), (4,4)}

Symmetric - aRb and bRa does not exist for all a,b in R, so false.

Asymmetric - loops and cycles exist so this is false.

Not symmetric - 1R2 which is in R and 2R1 which is not in R, so this is false.

Antisymmetric - loops exist so this is false.

Is my explanation correct? I am mainly confused at the not symmetric part.

Comment: Seems that there are only three things to show but you’ve done that. . Perhaps a simpler example: $aRb, aRc, cRa$

Comment: "Not True" is false, and "Not False" is true. If "Symmetric" is false, then "Not symmetric" is true. If "Not symmetric" is false, then "symmetric" is true. You cannot have them both false. Also, though it seems likely you have the right idea, the way you explain why "Symmetric" is false would actually require $R$ to be empty. The reason "Symmetric" is false (and "Not symmetric" is true) is what you point out for Not symmetric: $1R2$ but not $2R1$. Antisymmetric is false because $1R3$ and $3R1$. Asymmetric is false because Antisymmetric is false. But also because $1R1$.